# EF Core FromSqlRaw with column variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Attempting to set the column as a parameter in `FromRawSql`. Query always returns null, I understand this is because the SQL is compiled before parameter values are set. How can I pass the column name into the query as a parameter?

What I'm trying:

```
var param = new SqlParameter[] {
                        new SqlParameter("@col", dataDiscriminator),
                        new SqlParameter("@value", itemDiscValue)
                    };

var thisq = context.Devices.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE @col = @value", param);                        
var thisDevice = thisq.SingleOrDefault();
```

Will produce the SQL:

```
DECLARE @col nvarchar(4) = N'Name';
DECLARE @value nvarchar(26) = N'Registration Template';

SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE @prop = @value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  not use parameter for table or column name. Try this

```
var param = new SqlParameter[] {
                        new SqlParameter("@value", itemDiscValue)
                    };
var thisq = context.Devices.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * from Devices 
WHERE [{dataDiscriminator}] = @value", param).ToList();                        
 var thisDevice = thisq.SingleOrDefault();
```

I don' t know where dataDiscriminator data from but always remember about the sql script injections.

Comment: I have learned that FromSqlInterpolated is the preferred method to pass parameters in this way. "The FromSqlInterpolated and ExecuteSqlInterpolated methods allow using string interpolation syntax in a way that protects against SQL injection attacks" -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql which may be better since my parameters can be set by a client.